# Details from a string in bold

Tags: vba, ms-access

I have a function to generate a text: Voornaam PlattenTuub on a form.
Now I want to change the layout: Voornaam mist be bold, PlattenTuub must be Italic.
How can I change that (see below).

```
Public Function fConcatPlat(intRit As Integer) As String
strBuild = ""

strSQL = "SELECT * FROM [tblPlattenTuub] WHERE [Rit] = " & intRit & " ORDER BY [Rit] ;"
Set db = CurrentDb
Set rs = db.OpenRecordset(strSQL, dbOpenForwardOnly)
With rs
  Do While Not .EOF
   If ![PlattenTuub] = 1 Then
    strBuild = strBuild & " " & ![Voornaam] & " -"
    Else
    strBuild = strBuild & " " & ![Voornaam] & " " & ![PlattenTuub] & " -"
    End If
      .MoveNext
  Loop
End With
strBuild = Left$(strBuild, Len(strBuild) - 1)
rs.Close
Set rs = Nothing
fConcatPlat = strBuild
End Function
```

Answer (score 1):

I assume you want to display the result in a TextBox. Set the *.TextFormat* Property of it to "*Rich Text*". Than change your vba code to:

```
strBuild = strBuild & " <b>" & ![Voornaam] & "</b>"
If ![PlattenTuub] = 1 Then
    strBuild = strBuild & " <i>" & ![PlattenTuub] & "</i>"
End If
strBuild = strBuild & " -"
```

Comment: The textbox is on a report. How and where can I change the property to Rich text (on that form?). On first sight I see no possibility.

Comment: Now I found the property but when I try to change that in Rich text I get an error: The setting is not valid for this property.                   An invalid condition was encountered by Access due to a value that you entered for a field or table property.  Review the table for any changes which might be out of range or are not supported by the table.

Examine any changes that you may have made to the table and, if possible, revert back to a previous copy of either the database or the table to determine the differences in your settings.

Answer (score 1):

Add an unbound Rich Text TextBox to your Report, then set its Control Source to:

`='<b>' & [Voornaam] & '</b>' & IIf([PlattenTuub] = 1, '', '- <i>' & [PlattenTuub] & '</i>')`

You can do the same thing on a Form.

Alternatively, you can add a new computed field VenP to the RecordSource for the Report or Form. Replace

```
 SELECT * FROM ...
```

with

```
 SELECT '<b>' & [Voornaam] & '</b>' & IIf([PlattenTuub] = 1, '', '- <i>'
   & [PlattenTuub] & '</i>') AS VenP, * FROM ...
```

Then you can simply use VenP as the Control Source for your textbox.
This is my preferred method for a computed TextBox on a continuous form, because the values are calculated when the form loads, so they don't flicker as the continuous form is scrolled.